# Non homogenous differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

> Given the following equations:
> $$x'=-x+y-1$$
> $$y'=-x-y+3$$
> When $t=0$, $x=0$ and $y=3$
> Find the general solution for $x$ and $y$ in terms of $t$.

I have already differentiated $x'$ and reduced the equation to find
$$x''+2x'+2x=2$$

I then took the equation to be equal to 0 and used the auxilliary equation and followed through to find the roots to be $$-1 \pm i $$
I then found the PI to be $1$ from $x=2/2$ (unsure about this as there isnt a constant since there is no $x$ involved?)

Therefore leading to the general solution for $x$:
$$x(t)=e^{-t}(A \cos t +B \sin t)+1$$

Can anyone please verify this and help me with how to now find y in terms of t as I am unsure of how to proceed.

Thanks!

Comment: You've only provided one equation. And you'll need to typeset your working using [Latex](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), writing your working in words is too cumbersome for most people to bother with.

Comment: Your $x(t)$ is correct. And to find $y(t)$, note that you can use the first equation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything you did is correct:
$$x''+2x'+2x=0$$
$$\implies r^2+2r+2=(r+1)^2-i^2=(r+1-i)(r+1+i)=0$$
$$r= -1\pm i$$
Therefore the solution to the homogeenous equation is :
$$x(t)=e^{-t}(A \cos t +B \sin t)$$
And the particular solution is
$$x_p=A \implies A =1$$
$$x(t)=e^{-t}(A \cos t +B \sin t)+1$$
You still need to apply the initial conditions given in the problem.
$$x(0)=0 \implies A=-1$$
$$x(t)=e^{-t}(-\cos t +B \sin t)+1$$
And find $y(t)$:
$$y=x'+x+1$$
$$ye^t=(xe^t)'+e^t$$
$$ye^t=(-\cos t +B \sin t +e^t)'+e^t$$
$$ye^t=\sin t +B \cos t +2e^t$$
$$y(t)=e^{-t}(\sin t +B \cos t) +2$$
Apply intitial condition...
$$ y(0) =3 \implies B=1$$

Comment: thankyou! I tried to find y(t) by substituting back into the initial equations but got lost in a long unfactorized mess of values that I was struggling to simplify. Do I need to apply the initial conditions to find y(t)?

Comment: Note that you have $x(0)=0$ you can simplify $x(t)$ @anon12352432

Comment: Nite that $y=x'+x+1$ @anon12352432

Comment: I added the answer for $y$ @anon12352432